Is it necessary to add health-check config for ecs.CfnTaskDefinition.ContainerDefinitionProperty?
For a ECS FARGATE, is it necessary to set health-check for CfnTaskDefinition.ContainerDefinitionProperty?
For a ECS FARGATE, how does health_check for CfnTaskDefinition.ContainerDefinitionProperty work?
and who uses this check result?
1 If only one container for app task, health-check of target group will return service status for ELB.
So I think it is not necessary to add health check config for CfnTaskDefinition.ContainerDefinitionProperty.
2 If app+fluentbit+datadog = 3 containers, health-check config is necessary?
I can not find any doc which describes how  health-check works in container.
I want to know who calls the health-check and uses the check result.
